# Why do my Next.JS pages not re-run javascript when the page is viewed again?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a next.js app set up and written entirely in react, currently including the homepage, which is just a temporary placeholder using react components.

The real homepage was delivered to me in the form of a static site with an HTML file and several CSS+JS files. I can't just display the static HTML files right out of the public directory because I need the 'real' React navigation component to be displayed. I converted the HTML files to .js files, chopped off their static nav, and wrapped them in an export default so that I could import them into the appropriate route file in /pages, displaying them using return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: homepage }} />; which allows my _app.tsx file to wrap it in all the usual stuff that applies the nav to the pages, context, providers, etc etc.

This seems to work great, however when I navigate away to one of my real pages and navigate back to the homepage it doesn't seem to re-run the javascript files the way a regular webpage would. Animations don't start, hero slider images are displayed one under the other, basically as if none of the JS is happening.

Am I approaching this from entirely the wrong angle, or is there just something I'm missing? I would prefer not to convert the HTML file I was given into React components at this time, so priority would be given to whatever solution keeps the original HTML file in its closest form so that the original programmers can update it without hassle. Why is none of my JS re-running?

Comment: And why don't you convert them into  react components right away, if you are using react, using `useEffect` hooks, to run the javascript on page load?

Comment: The original developers need to be able to deliver updates to the homepage over time, and converting it into react components would prevent them from being able to do that. The project needs to deliver their code as in-tact as possible with as little effort from me as possible.